# Maven: inheritance of artifacts built by assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am building our Web-application using Maven Assembly plug-in. This is motivated by a requirement to extract some data out of special plug-ins. The fragment of assembly descriptor demonstrates this:

```
    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <includes>
            <include>org.myproject.module:*:jar</include>
        </includes>
        <unpackOptions>
            <includes>
                <include>images/**</include>
                <include>install/**</include>
                <include>mappings/**</include>
            </includes>
        </unpackOptions>
        <outputDirectory>./WEB-INF/myproject-modules/${artifact.name}</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
```

All plug-ins with groupId=org.myproject.module have this special treatment and extraction of module-specific folders.

Now, I have a requirement to build another WAR with exactly the same approach, but different set of modules. Is there any way to nicely extend my original POM, and simply add dependencies, *without need to have a copy* of my assembly descriptor(s) (stored in src/main/assembly)?

Simply extending pom fails with missing assembly descriptor, which is physically found in parent:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>   
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a chance to reference descriptor instead of storing it as a file in a project folder. There're <descriptorRef>s but it seems that only predefined descriptor references are supported, with no mechanism to add custom ones. May I be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html) of how to share assembly descriptors between projects in the assembly plugin docs.  That should work if you're not using assembly components; I've seen references to classpath issues when using components with this method.

Comment: I should have been more patient and careful with this documentation. Thanks.